Question about rename command
The perl rename command is powerful. It can look for string patterns and replace these. If your files have a similar time stamp, this would work:
rename -n 's/ XXX.*?]//' *
This would remove all strings looking like [ XXX...]]. So it would not matter if some files have a different time stamp.
How could I modify this line to rename folder names ONLY in a certain directory?

This command is already limited to files in a certain directory: the current one. Change your current directory to the one you want to limit it to, and presto!
